# Assigning value field of a struct in a Map<..,struct> deletes unspecified values

Tags: struct, vespa

Im following the documentation:
https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/document-json-update-format.html#assign-map-field

When I update a single field of a struct in a map to struct the unspecified values are deleted.  Is this an error or expected behavior?  I would like to retain the other values.

Before the update the object looks like this

```
...
"status":[  
   {  
      "key":0,
      "value":{  
         "f1":"before",
         "f2":"before2"
      }
   }
]
...
```

I make an http PUT request

```
{
   "update":"id:ITEM:ITEM::ITEM_1",
   "fields":{
      "status{0}":{
         "assign":{
            "f1: "changed"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

after the PUT, the f1 field changes but the f2 field is deleted

```
"status":[
   {
      "key":0,
      "value":{
         "f1":"changed"
      }
   }
]
```

```
field status type map<int, status> {
     indexing: summary
     struct-field key { indexing: attribute }
     struct-field value.f1 { indexing: summary | attribute}
     struct-field value.f2 { indexing: summary | attribute}
}

struct status {
     field f1 type string {}
     field f2 type string {}
}
```

Comment: We were just working on improving the documentation, not done yet but the link has changed to https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/document-json-format.html#assign-map-field - please feed back suggestions for improvements!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [Document Field Path Syntax](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/document-field-path.html)  to update individual map entries.

```
{
   "update":"id:ITEM:ITEM::ITEM_1",
   "fields":{
      "status{0}.f1": { "assign": "changed" }
   }
}
```